# Unable to determine end of video on Apple Watch WKInterfaceInlineMovie

Tags: ios, swift, video, beta, watchos-3

I am unable to determine end of video on Apple Watch `WKInterfaceInlineMovie`

Using a `WKInterfaceInlineMovie`, I am able to control playback of video (to start, pause, and play from the current position), however as far as I can see there is **no** callback or `delegate` to notify me that the video has reached the end, thus when the user taps to play and the video is at the end, nothing happens.

I would like to know when to call `playFromBeginning()` again.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You could get the duration of the video. When the video reaches that duration you could fire off your own notification to call a function that restarts the video? Just a thought.

Comment: @NSGangster - I thought of that, but that requires keeping track of the length of the video throughout starts and stops, etc. It seems strange that there is no delegate method for reaching the end of playback.

Comment: Looking through docs on AVFoundation. Found that there is a notification on AVPlayerItem that you can register a selector for. Is there anyway to use AV Foundation with watchkit? I know its kind of a pain but you would have your notification there. Look through these [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification)

Comment: There is now AV support on the watch, however I specifically am using the WKInterfaceInlineMovie.

Comment: Try `setLoops:` method? if set it true, the video will start again when it reach the end